# "Your project is misconfigured" error when publishing results of provider verification with Gradle and Kotlin

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl, pact, pact-jvm

I posted this in [GitHub](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/issues/1466) 14 days ago but have had no response. I'm hoping a StackOverflow user might know the answer?

When I run

> gradle pactVerify -Ppact.verifier.publishResults=true

I am getting an error:

> Your project is misconfigured, was expecting a 'pact' configuration in
> the build, but got a String with value '' instead. Make sure there is
> no property that is overriding 'pact'.

The pact verifies successfully without `-Ppact.verify.publishResults=true` on the command line.

I am using Gradle 6.8.3 with Java 11 and Kotlin 1.4.20 on Windows 10 Professional. (I have also tried Gradle 7.1 and Kotlin 1.4.31)

I have reviewed the [documentation](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/provider/gradle#publishing-verification-results-to-a-pact-broker) and tried to find related issues without success.

My Gradle build file uses the Kotlin DSL and I've tried Groovy DSL as well with the same result. This is what it looks like (with URLs elided):

```
plugins {
    id("au.com.dius.pact") version "4.2.14"
}

pact {
    broker {
        pactBrokerUrl = "https://..."
    }
    reports {
        defaultReports()
    }
    serviceProviders {
        create("provider") {
            protocol = "http"
            host = "localhost"
            port = 8081
            path = "/"
            version = "test"

            hasPactWith("consumer") {
                pactSource = url("https://...")
            }
        }
    }
}
```